# Show that there are two powers of three that have the same last three digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics

in a discrete math course i'm currently following. In the proofs section which happen to be the lecture right after the peigon hole principle, there is this problem :

```
 1. In this problem you will show that some power of 3 ends in the digits 001.
     (i) Show that there are two powers of three that have the same last
three digits. Hint: consider the first thousand powers, 3^1, 3^2, . . . , 3^1000 =
3, 9, 27, . . ., and the fact that the last three digits can’t be 000 for any of
these (why?).
```

I have no idea how to even capture the last three digits.

1. Is there a formula?
2. Is there any prerequisite material i need to cover before attempting
   the exercise?
3. I'm i asked to present a proof?
4. how do i even approach this?

by the way i looked all over the internet, and i found absolutely nothing like this 
 ever discussed before.

thanks everyone.

Comment: The hint is pretty good, but the bit about the $000$ isn't really essential.  Look at the $1001$ numbers $3^1, 3^2, \cdots, 3^{1001}$.  Can they all end in different blocks of three?  How many blocks of three are there?

Comment: The last digit must be $1$, $3$, $7$, or $9$. So even looking at the first $10^2\cdot4+1=401$ powers, there would have to be a repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to work out the actual last three digits of any of these. You are going to use the pigeon hole principle.

First, think about the possibilities for the last three digits. They go from '000' and '001' all the way to '998' and '999'. Hopefully it's obvious that there are 1000 different possibilities.

Second, recognise that '000' is actually impossible. That leaves a maximum of 999 different possibilities.

So we have 1000 different powers of 3 and 999 possible last three digits. At least one of the last three digits must be repeated.

Comment: oh man thanks i feel so dumb right now.